# Google TV : Supported Android devices 0 devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, google-tv

[image: apk 0 devices]
[image link](https://postimg.cc/87CxrgxG)

this is my Google TV application manifest which i uploaded on google play end i get message "0 devices are suported" can someone tell my what i'm making wrong
(i want to target googleTV devices)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*******"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.081" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/> 
    <uses-feature android:name="com.google.android.tv" android:required="true"/> 


    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_min"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" > 
            <!-- android:screenOrientation="landscape" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to use "aapt dump badging " to see, but it looks like something in your APK is requesting native tools (Native Platforms in your chart) - perhaps a library you included?

For sure using anything native will keep you from being seen on a Google TV currently.

I'm also a bit concerned about the uppercase TV in Features.

Answer (score 1):

I think your minSdkVersion needs to be 11.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_market_publishing_checklist

Comment: The rest of the manifest file looks OK. Are you requesting portrait mode in any of your activities? Are you using the NDK at all?

Comment: i'am using java . no i'm not requesting portrait mode